# Prolog избежать одинаковых вопросов пользователю

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Всем привет, разрабатываю небольшую экспертную систему на языке SWI - Prolog. Столкнулся с таким вопросом. У меня есть набор фактов, а также is_true, и is_false, которые задаются пользователем

```
animal(dog)  :- is_true("есть мех"), is_true("говорит уууффф").
animal(cat)  :- is_true("есть мех"), is_true("говорит мяу").
animal(duck) :- is_true("есть перья"), is_true("говорит кря").
animal(pig) :- is_false("есть мех"), is_false("говорит мяу").

is_true(Q) :-
        format("~s?\n", [Q]),
        read(yes).

is_false(W):- not(is_true(W)).
```

В таком случае все работает, однако, все вопросы идут по порядку, и дублируются. Ниже привожу то, что запрашивает у пользователя программа

```
есть мех?
yes.
говорит уууффф?
no.
есть мех?
no.
есть перья?
no.
есть мех?
no.
говорит мяу?
no.
[{'X': 'pig'}]
```

Как видно, вопрос "Есть мех" вызвался три раза, хотя понятно, что для корректной работы достаточно спросить и один раз. Подскажите, как можно оптимизировать данный код, чтобы избежать дубляжа вопросов. Я так думаю, что можно как то задать вопросы в виде правил, и к каждому животному привязать список из номеров вопросов, на которые ответы - ДА. Но как именно это сделать, я не понимаю. Всем заранее спасибо за помощь.

P.S. pl - файл я запускаю через Python, при помощи библиотеки PySwip. Если запускать через SWI-Prolog проблема точно такая же.

SWI-Prolog 8.4.1
Python 3.6.8
PySwip 0.2.10